# End thread when reference to object is dropped

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a `List` of objects that sometimes spawn a thread and maintain a `bool` that terminates said thread; however, the references for these objects are occasionally dropped when the parent `List` is cleared via `List.clear()`.

This obviously results in orphaned threads that I can no longer terminate.

**I know that I can solve the problem by making sure that all threads are canceled before clearing the `List`,** but I'm curious if it's possible to determine if the reference to the object that spawned the thread is dropped.

Basically I've got this common structure:

```
List<Foo> myFoos = new List<Foo>();

class Foo {
    public bool keepThreadAlive = false;

    public void StartThread () {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(() => {
            while(keepThreadAlive) {
                // Do stuff until told to stop
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Where `myFoos` is cleared occasionally.

Is it possible to sense the loss of reference to `Foo` from within the unnamed thread and terminate the `while`?

Comment: Why don't you implement your own FooList class inheriting from List, so you can override the Clear/Add/Remove methods.

Comment: "Not Really" - not in a very expedite and reliable manner anyway. I would encapsulate the "Clear" access (not necessarily in another type) to properly perform house keeping. However, if also supplying the 'source list' to the thread then it could see if it is still 'contained in' it as part of the keep-running logic .. but that feels like extra bleed and requires that the source itself remains the same object.

Comment: @thepirat000 That's a good idea for encapsulation, but (correct me if I'm wrong) doesn't it result basically the first solution? I'm assuming you would just enhance the `clear` method to make sure all children had `keepThreadAlive` set to false?

Comment: @user2864740 Please elaborate. Do you suggest I keep the thread as a member rather than creating it though a lambda? How does one check if a thread is 'still contained in' another? I've not done that before.

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood I don't particularly suggest such; but given a list of `myFoos` - and a method to determine if a particular `Foo` is in it - it should be quite possible for the thread to notice that it's 'parent' `Foo` is no longer in the list and thus terminate itself.

Comment: @user2864740 It sounds like you could provide a good answer, if you'd be willing to write one up. 'No' is perfectly legitimate. But I'd like to see what you're suggesting fleshed out a bit.

Comment: @user2864740 In my case the source object will always remain the same object, so what you're suggesting could be viable.

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood Would switching to an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) work in this case? It implements `ICollection<T>`, but is not a List. It removes the burden of creating a custom type; as long as the events are properly reacted to.

Comment: @user2864740 Hmm, yes that could be a solution too! Nice work! Please, if you have the time, make an answer mentioning all the things you just did. It would help others in my situation I'm sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm curious if it's possible to determine if the reference to the object that spawned the thread is dropped

It is not, not in a direct sense. .NET has a `WeakReference<T>` class that can track whether an object is still referenced by *any* other variable, but in this case it's unlikely you'd be able to create a situation where the list contains the only variable referencing the object. I.e. as long as any variable still references the object, the `WeakReference<T>` object will indicate that the object is still alive.

In the code example you've provided here, your thread is running code inside the object being referenced in the list. You're using an anonymous method, but assuming that code uses the object itself, the anonymous method will be contained in an anonymous class that itself references the object, causing a second, persistent reference.

You could try to bypass that by putting the thread code into a static method, where the object reference itself is retrieved from the `WeakReference<T>` object if available (and the thread would exit when not available). But assuming the thread is using the object with any sort of regularity, it's likely the code in the static method would keep the object alive for long enough periods of time that the GC wouldn't have a chance to notice it in the unused state.

As commenter [user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238106/end-thread-when-reference-to-object-is-droped#comment52358783_32238106) notes, there are other, more explicit approaches you can take. I'm not very fond of the idea of polling the list (this can be especially bad if the list can be large, and is wasteful in any case), but if you are able to use an observable list, such as `ObservableCollection<T>`, that could work. To do that, you've have to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event and handle it appropriately:

```
myFoos.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove ||
        e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
    {
        foreach (Foo foo in e.OldItems)
        {
            foo.CancelThread(); // or whatever
        }
    }
};
```

Note that the above is just the basic idea. There's not enough context in your question to know whether it would suffice or if, for example, you might need to do something special to handle new items being added to the collection (either via `Add` or `Replace` action).

Personally, it seems to me that if you know these items are only being "lost" when you clear the list, that the best approach is the one you already know about: just cancel all the tasks represented by the objects in the list *before* you clear the list.

Comment: Supueb! You provide great insight. I will likely do as you said in the end and use the simpler approach. Thank you for your time and expertise.